# Do Islamic countries have a higher than average porn consumption despite porn being banned in them?

Tags: islam, pornography

In the first place, I'm linking this wikipedia web page to show that, as a general rule, pornography seems to be banned in Islamic countries (although it doesn't show data for all of them, it looks like a reasonable guess).

[Pornography laws by region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pornography_laws_by_region)

In second place, I'm linking these other web pages which explain that, despite of that, Islamic countries seem to have a higher than usual porn consumption. Mentioning for example things like six of the top eight porn-searching countries are Muslim states or that countries like Pakistan or Turkey top on search terms like "animal sex" or "child porn".

[Do Muslims watch Pornography?](http://www.freerepublic.com/focus/news/3247669/posts)

[Porn Websites Among Most Visited In Islamic Countries](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/porn-websites-among-most-viewed-islamic_n_2130317)

[Why porn is exploding in the Middle East](https://www.salon.com/2015/01/15/why_porn_is_exploding_in_the_middle_east_partner/)

I want to make clear that my question is not just about that they consume higher pornography than normal, it's about that they have that high consumption despite being banned, as a general rule, in their countries.

So to answer the question with a "yes" the yes must cover the idea that Islamic countries have

- a higher than average porn consumption and
- pornography is generally banned in their countries.

Comment: Google shows that it varies widely by country: https://trends.google.com/trends/explore/GEO_MAP/1553862000?hl=en-US&tz=-540&q=porn&sni=3

Comment: Please pick a specific source and a particular quote for us to examine.  As is, it's not clear what the notable claim is.

Comment: There's a whole bunch of claims in the FreeRepublic link with various levels of truth to them, not at all helped by the fact that the writer doesn't seem to cite any of his claims.  I would recommend focusing on a single article and a single claim, it is too easy to accidently fall into a hole of trying to prove or disprove everything in every article.

Comment: https://www.psypost.org/2020/05/a-conservative-religious-environment-strongly-increases-the-chances-of-adolescent-viewing-56919

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic Before placing a bounty, it would be good to address the criticisms in the comments above - namely, that the question doesn't focus on a single notable claim, as required by this site's policy.

Comment: Note, also, that porn searches aren't that good a proxy for porn consumption.  People bookmark things!  At best you'll get an indication of the number of consumers, but little about how much they consume.

Comment: Didn't 'Hub release some statics a while ago? Maybe those hold some indication? At work, so can't check nsfw content.

Comment: What constitutes as a porn consumption measure? Money spent for porn? Time spent looking at porn? Both may be hard to estimate in a place where porn is banned.

Comment: Indeed, bookmarking might be avoided where porn is banned because it would be evidence of a crime, leading to more searches.

Comment: anecdote: I recall a ride-along journalist in Iraq and footage while searching a house in Iraq, a soldier holding up a a magazine and noted that they *always* find porn magazines. So estimates for black market hard-copy might be something to look for. Surely some post-doc worked on this topic.